# parsing array has 2 value in every row using jquery

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have array saved in the localsorage of iPhone app .. when I alert it it return

```
[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
```

how I can parse it with foreach??

Here is the code that store the array

```
var flist=new Array();
           var flist = $.map(response.data, function(index, friend) {
    return {
        name: friend.name,
        id: friend.id
    };
});
        localStorage.setItem('user_list', JSON.stringify(flist));
        } else {
            alert("Error!");
        }
    });
```

also here is how I parse it

```
$.each(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user_list')), function(key, val) {

        $('ul#merchant-list').append('<li> '+ val.name + '</li>');


        });
```

but it return nothing.

Comment: Try adding an alert for `val.name` in the parsing function.  The code looks fine.  I'm deleting my answer because it doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: I tried something  $.each(localStorage.getItem('user_list'), function(key, val) {

        $('ul#merchant-list').append('<li> '+ val.name + '</li>');


        }); it return undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined

Comment: @tushar gupta I can't ... it is iPhone app

Comment: @ManMann added iPhone tag :)

Comment: If you do not have a console (I never did iPhone development so I do not know), stringify the result using `JSON.stringify()` and place the string in a div. make it available here if you cant figure it out once you have the objects.

Comment: @ManMann, welcome to debugging.  You need to see if you ever reach the code that saves to local storage, see each object as it's being serialized, and see each item as it's being unserialized.  Along with what MasterAM said, you could use something like [jsprint](http://brigand.github.io/jsprint/) which is like console.log but the DOM version.

Comment: check this
alert(localStorage.getItem('user_list'));
show [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Comment: no one can help guys?

Comment: is there a way to change the way that I store the array?

Comment: You should provide more information. Try to check the array before it gets stored. I see 2 potential issues: 1. You are declaring the `flist` variable twice (BTW, I would go for `=[]` instead of `= new Array()`). 2. The `$.map()` function accepts the arguments the other way around: `jQuery.map( arrayOrObject, callback( value, indexOrKey ) )`.